# how to get column names in table in sqlplus 12c

Tags: sqlplus

I am executing the following command with these results:

```
 SQL> select * from employee;
            12 sachin                    48000         23
            13 raja                      49000         23
            35 vikas                     40000         26
            11 sau                       22000         24
            23 viru                      40000         26
            87 raju                       4500
```

I would also like to get the name of the column. How may I do this?

Comment: It looks like you're _not_ getting the column names actually.  What is your exact question?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Set heading on` - this will toggle the column headers on or off.